# Github - SSH permisson for operations

Tags: ssh, github

Good morning, magicians,

I have just booted my machine to windows due to gaming issues (unnecessary information), and require github for programming work. I followed the standard procedure for creating an SSH key, but the following log appears:

```
Cloning into 'Robotics4fun'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '140.82.114.4' to the list of known hosts.
\302\226git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My guess (accurate, if i may brag) is due "\302\226" trash characters spurious before the "git@github.com" command.

Comment: What actual git command are you running? What relevant settings are in your git config? What relevant settings are in your ssh config?

Comment: It appears when I try to clone some repository i.e. ```git clone repo-url```

Comment: git config output:

http://codepad.org/3PFdVSWD